# Django per-object permissions

Tags: django, django-models, rbac

I have users that each are associated with a list of real estate properties they are allowed to access. Multiple users may have permission to view the same site.

How would I set this up in django?

I have the:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    last_session_time_online = models.IntegerField()
    total_time_online = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

and the

```
class Site(models.Model):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
    ...Other stuff...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

Comment: `Site` here isn't the Django contrib.site object, but a property the user is allowed to access, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basic many-to-many stuff:

```
 class Site(models.Model):
     site_name = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
     allowed_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

 ...

 sam = User.objects.get(username = 'sam')
 frodo = User.objects.get(username = 'frodo')

 hobbithole = Site.objects.get(site_name = 'The Hobbit Hole')
 hobbithole.allowed_users.add(sam, frodo)

 frodo.site_set.all() # Should return "The Hobbit Hole" object, and any other place frodo's allowed to visit.

 somesite.allowed_users.exists(user = frodo) # returns True if frodo is in the site's set of allowed users.
```

If you don't want to clutter `Site`, you can also create an intermediate "through" table.  That creates a layer of indirection, but allows you to add things to the through table like degrees of permission, if you want.  You can use the `auth` module's `groups` feature on that table to define "groups that have access to the keys" and "groups that can modify the property" and so on.

[Many To Many Fields in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields)

Answer (score 2):

This came up recently, but I can't find the relevant question on SO.  Instead here are some links that I had saved from that discussion to read later:

- [Handling object permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-object-permissions) - Django Docs
- [Django Object Permissions 1.2](http://blogs.osuosl.org/kreneskyp/2010/12/21/django-object-permissions-13/) - Oregon State University Open Source Lab
- [Django Object Permissions Proof of Concept](http://opensource.washingtontimes.com/blog/2009/dec/10/django-object-permissions-proof-concept/) - The Washington Times

Answer (score 2):

Django now supports object permissions. Besides [Handling Object Permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-object-permissions), which has been linked to in another answer, the [REST Framework guide to permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions) is worth reading.

You will want to add code to the `Meta` subclass of your model for each permission:

```
class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ('edit_this_model', 'Edit this model'),
    )
```

If you are using south, you may need to run `manage.py syncdb --all` after updating the model.

To test if a user is authenticated, use a command such as this:

```
user.has_perm('your_app_name. edit_this_model')
```

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of plugins [here](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/) that do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try Django-Guradian. You can use it to assign object level permissions to Users/Groups.